# Adding assets from the command line

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am using a set of Hyperledger 1.0.2 docker images with composer 0.11.3
The practice network I use is [basic-sample-network](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages/basic-sample-network) which comes with a SampleParticipant and a SampleAsset.
I am able to deploy the participant from the command line using composer participant add along with the JSON snippet.
I have not found an equivalent command line approach to insert the SampleAsset into the asset registry. When I use the composer-rest-server to POST the JSON snippet defining the SampleAsset, it returned the following error

```
Error: Peer has rejected transaction '4d2...91f' with cdoe MVCC_READ_CONFLICT
```

I then re-submitted after reading a comment on BatchTimeout and locking which I didn't modify as I am a single user on a baby chain. The second time, the REST server returned

```
Error: Failed to add object with ID 'assetId:1' as the object already exists)
```

I could verify the asset registry was updated with composer network list:

```
name:       basic-sample-network
models:
  - org.hyperledger.composer.system
  - org.acme.sample
scripts:
  - lib/sample.js
registries:
  org.acme.sample.SampleAsset:
    id:           org.acme.sample.SampleAsset
    name:         Asset registry for org.acme.sample.SampleAsset
    registryType: Asset
    assets:
      assetId:1:
        $class:  org.acme.sample.SampleAsset
        assetId: assetId:1
        owner:   resource:org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant#Toby
        value:   new value
  org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant:
    id:           org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant
    name:         Participant registry for org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant
    registryType: Participant
    assets:
      Toby:
        $class:        org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant
        participantId: Toby
        firstName:     Tobias
        lastName:      Hunter
```

Why this odd behaviour from the REST server which complained with MVCC_READ_CONFLICT but yet inserted the record and is there a way I missed of inserting the SampleAsset from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

hmmm.. not sure why you got an MVCC error (as you say, can't have been to do with the asset that was indeed added, as you've shown).

`composer transaction submit` is the method to submit a transaction to (say) add an asset from the command line - examples in the docs ('Example command') and another below:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.transaction.submit.html

https://gist.github.com/jt-nti/137a039eb21992136c3f3e54c5c50fa5#file-org-hyperledger-composer-system-addasset-txt